# How to add Metadata for Rackspace Cloudfile Object?

Tags: .net, sdk, metadata, rackspace, cloudfiles

Using the cloud-files .NET API, I don't see a way to add meta data to objects. I only see a method to get meta data from object. Is there a way to add meta data to a file I have uploaded? I read the doc here at http://openstacknetsdk.org/docs/ , but I don't see anything regarding adding meta data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** [Release 1.1.3.0](https://github.com/openstacknetsdk/openstack.net/releases/tag/v1.1.3.0) contains the fix for this issue.

---

There is currently a GitHub issue for this request:
[Complete methods for object metadata](https://github.com/openstacknetsdk/openstack.net/issues/93)

As of right now, the feature has been implemented in the [Rackspace fork of the project](https://github.com/rackspace/openstack.net), but has not yet been merged into the main project yet. I know the RackConnect team at Rackspace is working on getting a new release out within the next few days, so stay tuned!

Disclaimer: I work at Rackspace, though not on the RackConnect team.

Comment: I did try out `cloudFilesProvider.UpdateObjectMetadata` . It adds the new metadata passed in as Dictionary. Now, say i added 5 metadata items. when i needed to update a single metadata, i called `cloudFilesProvider.UpdateObjectMetadata` with only that metadata in the dictionary and called `cloudFilesProvider.UpdateObjectMetadata`.  This second call essentially removed all existing metadata and added this metadata. Is it the expected behavior?

Comment: Yes, that is the expected behavior. You can track my progress updating the documentation in [my Documentation branch on GitHub](https://github.com/sharwell/openstack.net/compare/openstacknetsdk:master...Documentation). As you can see, I'll be getting to `IObjectStorageProvider` very soon and these things will be made clear. You need to call `GetObjectMetadata`, update *that* `Dictionary`, and then pass the updated dictionary back in the call to `UpdateObjectMetadata`.